# XAML IntelliSense not working in VS15

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know if something happened to the IntelliSense at VisualStudio 2015?
I was developing my app using VS13 and with ReSharper the IS was working fine, after I installed VS15 it doesn't work anymore (please see image below).

[image]

This same code was working without error and now I get that... By the way, this is a fresh installation of VS15 in a fresh installation of W8.1 Pro. 
I tried reinstalling ReSharper, but it still doesn't work!
Does anyone know how to solve this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the official Xamarin.Forms forum their is also a topic with the same problem.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46185/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-regression-when-editing-xaml-files

The last answer from XamarinHQ is:

> "Hi all, Intellisense for Xamarin.Forms XAML files in VS 2015 does indeed use a different approach from the "Xamarin.Forms Intellisense" extension that is used in VS 2013.
>
> The new approach depends on an update to the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package. The new NuGet package that includes those dependencies has not yet been released (the Xamarin.Forms team is working to get it ready for release as soon as possible)."

So we need to wait till an update of Xamarin.Forms :(

**UPDATE**: XamarinHQ hopes that the Prerelease of Xamarin.Forms will arrive Monday 27th of July.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wasn't aware of that. I guess we'll have to wait then... And that's what Xamarin called same-day support, right :)

Comment: Well, it's the same-day support. For Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android. But unfortunately not for Xamarin.Forms :(

Comment: Yeah, don't worry mate, it is ok, I still love Xamarin :)